# Remove default object from google maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to remove all the default object or places from google maps. I hope to know is this easier or building on overlay is easier. I want a blank map that supported by google. I will add the places or the object I need whenever I want , is this possible to do? `maps.clear()` doesn't add any help, I want to something `onCreate()` method or `onStart()` method to remove all the places and have a blank map with no places just road and buildings.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mapReady = true;
    Double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    Double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition).title("Current Location"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentPosition));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    mMap.setMapType();
    loadNearByPlaces(latitude,longitude);
}
```

This the start code I used.  How to modify it and make it do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide default icons for places and POIs and achieve your goal if you apply custom styling.

Have a look at the tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling

The styling wizard is available at:

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

For example to hide all businesses on the map you apply the following style

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```